# Filter data different from different pages using Data.php Helper class

Tags: php, magento

I join '**method**' column of sales_flat_order_payment table in sales_flat_shipment table In **Data.php**(Helper Class). Like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->getCollection();
$collection->join('sales/order_payment', 'order_id=parent_id' , 'method');
```

My issue is that there are 2 pages with search filter: **one page for Cash on delivery and another for Prepaid**.

I want to filter data different for different pages. Like for **cashdelivery** page i want to Filter this from Data.php:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('method', array('eq' => 'cashondelivery'));
```

And for **Prepaid** Page i want to filter this from Data.php

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('method', array('eq' => 'prepaid'));
```

I Tried to filter from same pages but there was **pagination issue** so i used Data.php.

I also tried current page url code also that also fail:

```
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
$currentpath = $url->getPath();

$linkpath = array('/cashdelivery/', 'cashdelivery/');
if(in_array($currentpath, $linkpath))
{
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('method', array('eq' => 'cashondelivery'));

}
```

Can anyone give me a tip to do this?